# Reduce "for loops for big data" and make improvement

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I am trying to make this code (that I made) as faster as possible. 
First, the code is as follows

```
#lemmas is list consisting of about 20,000 words. 
#That is, lemmas = ['apple', 'dog', ... ] 

#new_sents is list consisting of about 12,000 lists representing a sentence. 
#That is, new_sents = [ ['Hello', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'boy'], ['Hello', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'girl'], ... ]   

for x in lemmas:
        for y in lemmas:
            # prevent zero denominator 
            x_count = 0.00001
            y_count = 0.00001

            xy_count = 0
            ## Dice denominator 
            for i in new_sents:
                x_count += i.count(x) 
                y_count += i.count(y)

                if(x in i and y in i):
                    xy_count += 1

            sim_score = float(xy_count) / (x_count + y_count)
```

As you can see, there are so many iterations.. about 20,000 * 20,000 * 12,000, which are too big numbers. 
sim_score is Dice coeffient of two words. 
That is, xy_count means the number of word x and word y appeared together in the sentence and x_count and y_count mean the total number of word x and y shown in new_sents respectively.

I made my code which is too slow. 
Is there any better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To start, you could convert lemmas to a set, which should improve the lookup times.

Comment: Seems to me like the simplest solution would be to a. convert lemmas into a set, then iterate just over the sentences, and then iterate x and y just for the sentence.

Comment: Is it important to calculate your sim_score every combination of x and y? What are you doing with it? What's important about it?

Comment: @AaronHall Yes, though it will make some sparse matrix format, I need to do.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer you means using one loop for lemmas by converting lemmas in to a set?

Comment: Are you intentionally incrementing `x_count` for each instance of `y` and `y_count` for each instance of `x`? Seems like you are over counting (and doing a large amount of unnecessary work at the same time).

Comment: sim_score is updated for every pair of lemmas. Don't you want to store it?

Comment: can you explain what you're trying to accomplish in the first place? OK, the code returns the odds of count(any term of two words in `lemmas`) / count(words in any sentence in `new_sents`), but what's the objective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are computing each thing twice. Your score is symmetrical in x and y, so you can get a 2-fold speed up by doing this:

```
for x, y in itertools.combinations(lemmas, 2):
```

I am assuming you don't want to compare `lemmas[0]` with itself, otherwise you can use `combinations_with_replacement`.

The implementation will be faster if you look up `lemmas` from a set.

But you are still computing the same thing several times. You can take each lemma, count it in `news_sent` and store it.

Comment: itertools.combinations would change the algorithm, and possibly the scores being calculated

Comment: @AaronHall how? You get all possible pairs and the order is not important.

Comment: No, as you pointed out, you don't get the pair of lemma[0] with lemma[0] which his algorithm current counts and scores as well as the double counting, and the score is affected by each additional check.

Comment: @AaronHall but those cases are trivial, and most probably not what the OP wants to analyse. But if any case, if GodGJ wants, `combinations_with_replacement` does the trick.

Comment: @AaronHall CWR gives AA and AB, but not BA. itertools.product gives all possible combinations including order (the equivalent of both for loops, but with a faster implementation).

Comment: Then you've arbitrarily changed his calculations.

Comment: @AaronHall I haven't. The score is symmetrical, so xy is the same as yx, no need to compute twice. And since he is computing a similarity, the similarity of something with itself carries little meaning. I just trust the OP to know what he is doing and integrate things appropriately (I don't know what is he doing with them).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach by iterating the sentences, extracting word combinations and then counting them relative the single word occurrences. This is much more efficient, as it is the number of sentences * number_of_words_per_sentence^2

```
lemmas = ['apple', 'dog', 'foo', 'bar','Hello', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'boy', 'girl' ]

new_sents = [ ['Hello', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'boy'], ['Hello', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'girl']]

import itertools

#A counter is an auto updating dictionary for counting
from collections import Counter

#we initialize the counter with 1 for smoothing (avoiding 0)
lemmas = Counter({k:1 for k in lemmas})

#this is where we count the co-occurrences of words
coocurrs = Counter()

#we iterate the sentences, not the dictionary
for sentence in new_sents:
    #create all the word combinations in the sentences
    combos = (tuple(sorted(pair)) for pair in itertools.combinations(sentence, 2))

    #update a count for each word in the sentence
    lemmas.update(sentence)

    #update a count for each word combinations
    coocurrs.update(combos)

probabilities = {}

#convert to "probabilities"
for xy, score in coocurrs.iteritems():
    probabilities[xy] = score/float((lemmas[xy[0]]+lemmas[xy[1]]))

print probabilities
```

Comment: Well, this looks like an actual solution, but since you didn't tickle initial swarm's fancy, you don't win. But +1 for the effort.

Comment: @AaronHall that's why I hate answering Python questions. It's a race against time :(

Comment: This is actually a very interesting approach. That should indeed be the accepted one!

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you have an *n X n* matrix with the same members, the number of *unique*, non-repeating combinations is equal to:

(n^2 - n) / 2

where n = 20,000 in your case, that comes out to just under 200,000,000 iterations. The way your code is written now, however, there are 400,000,000 possibilities by doing:

```
for x in lemmas:
        for y in lemmas:
```

In other words, you're picking up situations where x == apples and y == oranges, in addition to x == oranges and y == apples. Presumably only one of those is necessary.

Finding a way to exclude those unnecessary 200,000,000 iterations will improve the speed.

Other than that, my suggestion would be to convert `new_sents` to a dictionary and totally remove this loop:

`for i in new_sents`

Doing both of those things should improve the speed by an appreciable amount. Then the total amount of iterations is kept to 200,000,000 and the look up at the end is with a dictionary, which is much faster than a list. This fast look up comes at the expense of memory, but for a length of 12,000 that shouldn't be an issue.